Parallelize R process that calls a flowWorkspace GatingSet
I'm working with flow cytometry data and have a large list of gates I want to add to my gating set. I'm using the BioConductor {flowWorkspace} package. I've tried using different parallel packages (snowfall, future, foreach, doParallel), and come across this error: external pointer is not valid. From my understanding, it seems the GatingSet object (gs in my code) I'm trying to iterate over is tied to one session (based off of this article: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html).
I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and knows of a solution or can point me in the right direction. Thanks so much. I've included an example code below of my process:
library(flowWorkspace)
#use example data
#remotes::install_github("https://github.com/RGLab/flowWorkspaceData/tree/master") 
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores - 1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

dataDir <- system.file("extdata",package="flowWorkspaceData")
gs_archive <- list.files(dataDir, pattern = "gs_bcell_auto",full = TRUE)
gs <- load_gs(gs_archive)

markers <-c("CD19", "CD20")

parent <- "/boundary/nonDebris/lymph/Live"

combos <- c("/boundary/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD19 & /nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD20",   "/boundary/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD19 & !/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD20",
            "!/boundary/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD19 & /nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD20",  "!/boundary/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD19 & !/nonDebris/lymph/Live/CD20")

combo_names <- c("CD19 & CD20",   "CD19 & !CD20",  "!CD19 & CD20",  "!CD19 & !CD20")

foreach(i=1:length(combos),
        .packages = "flowWorkspace",
        .verbose = F,
        .combine = "c"
        )  %dopar% {
          
          new_path <- eval(substitute(booleanFilter(v), list(v = as.symbol(combos[i]))))
          
          gs_pop_add(gs,
                     new_path,
                     parent = parent,
                     name = combo_names[i]) 
          
          recompute(gs, combo_names[i],
                              verbose = FALSE)
        }

stopCluster(cl)


try having each core load the object... if its too much overhead/too slow; then abandon parallelisation ideas, or ask the package provider if they can implement parallelization to their internals.
